# Find and delete a word followed by the next (n) lines in a file

Tags: shell, grep

I have one file called unclassified. A sample of it looks like this (each is on a new line):

```
OTU3
OTU9
OTU10
OTU1
OTU6
OTU4
```

I have another file called OTUcounts. A sample of it looks like this

```
>OTU4
TACGTACGTAGCTAGTCGATCGTAGTGCTCGTCATCGTGCTGCTGCTAGCTAGCTAGCTCGTCGTACGTACGTACGTCGTAGTACGCTGCATGCATGCATCGTACGTACGTACGCTAGTCGACTGACTAGCTGACTAGCTAGCTAGCTAGCTAGCTACGTACGATCGTACGTACGTACGTAGCTAGCTACGTAGCTAGCTAGTAGCTAGCTACGTACGTCGTCGTGTCGTCGTTTGT

>OTU6
AACGGCTAGCTAGCTAGCTGCTCTACGTCGATCATCGATGTCAGACTGCGGCAGACTCGTACGTACGTCGTCAGTCGCATCATCAGTCAGTAGACTGCTAGCTCAGATCCGCATCGATCAGTCGACTGCATGCATCAGTCAGCTAGCATCAGTCAGTACGCTAGACTAGTAAGGGGGGGGGCGATGATCGTCGTGCTTATTAGTAGTTTGACCGCGGCGCGCGCGAGACTAGTCGTA
```

How would I search the OTUcounts file and delete the OTUs listed in the unclassified file, to ultimatley end up with a new file that looks like OTUcounts but with the unclassifieds removed?

I have started to use:

```
grep -x -f unclassified OTUcounts > newOTUcounts
```

but I know it needs more added - I am fairly new to this.

Any ideas?

Comment: What did you mean by "_Each covers 4 lines_"? Did the editors mess up your `OTUcounts` sample?

Comment: Are the `>` really contained in the `OTUcounts` file?

Comment: The question this one was marked as a duplicate of is about selecting the entries that match another file, not deleting the entries that match, like this one. The exact opposite goal, in other words.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `awk` and store the OTU fields of `unclassified` in an array. When `OTUcounts` is read, test if the first field
is present in the array. If true, then set a flag and skip the next lines until the next OTU is found. Then reset the flag.

```
awk '
  NR==FNR{a[$1]; next}
  $1 in a{skip=1; next}
  skip{if (/^OTU/){skip=0; print}next} 1
' unclassified OTUcounts > newOTUcounts
```

Explanation:

```
awk '
  NR==FNR{       # if this is the first file...
    a[$1]        # save the first field in array `a` as array index
    next         # continue with the next line
  }
  $1 in a{       # if the first field is present in array `a`
    skip=1       # set a flag to skip the next lines
    next         # continue with the next line
  }
  skip{          # if the flag is set
    if (/^OTU/){ # if this is the next OTU
      skip=0     # reset the flag
      print      # print the current line
    }
    next         # continue with the next line
  }
  1              # print the current line
' unclassified OTUcounts > newOTUcounts
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using `v` option of `grep`:

`grep -v -f unclassified OTUcounts > newOTUcounts`

Answer (score 0):

We can indeed do it with only `grep`, by first generating a list of the OTUs to be kept and then using the `--after-context` option to print the three lines of context; finally we have to remove the line containing a group separator (--) which `grep` places between contiguous groups of matches.

```
grep OTU OTUcounts|grep -vwfunclassified|grep -xf- -A2 OTUcounts|grep -ve-- >newOTUcounts
```

Answer (score 0):

An alternative approach that uses GNU `sed` (And a shell like `bash` or `zsh` that understands `<(command)` redirection):

```
gsed -f <(while read otu; do echo "/^>${otu}\$/,+2d"; done < unclassified) OTUcounts > newOTUcounts
```

It turns each line of the `unclassified` file into a `sed` command that deletes any case of that OTU and the next two lines - `OTU3`, for example, is transformed into `/^>OTU3$/,+2d`